# Hooking into a WooCommerce filter

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, woocommerce, hook

Since a recent WooCommerce update users with the 'shopmanager' role are no longer to able to edit users with the 'subscriber' role.

I have found that the following function is responsible for this:

```
function wc_modify_editable_roles( $roles ) {
  if ( is_multisite() && is_super_admin() ) {
    return $roles;
  }
  if ( ! wc_current_user_has_role( 'administrator' ) ) {
    unset( $roles['administrator'] );
    if ( wc_current_user_has_role( 'shop_manager' ) ) {
      $shop_manager_editable_roles = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shop_manager_editable_roles', array( 'customer' ) );
      return array_intersect_key( $roles, array_flip( $shop_manager_editable_roles ) );
    }
  }
  return $roles;
}
add_filter( 'editable_roles', 'wc_modify_editable_roles' );
```

I need to add `subscriber` to the array in `apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shop_manager_editable_roles', array( 'customer' ) );` but that's where I get stuck.

**How do I hook into that filter to add the extra role?**

This is what I've got so far (doesn't work at all but it's a start:)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_manager_editable_roles', 'addanotherrole' );

function addanotherrole() {
  $shop_manager_editable_roles = array( 'customer', 'subscriber' );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted!

You need to return the new roles array like so:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_manager_editable_roles', 'addanotherrole' );
function addanotherrole($roles) {
    // add the additional role to the woocommerce allowed roles (customer)
    $roles[] = 'subscriber'; 

    // return roles array
    return $roles;
```

I hope that helped!